# How to override a ConfigField variable from Release with a Flavor ConfigField?

Tags: android, build.gradle

I'm working on an app that - on its release version - checks if the phone is rooted and prevents it from working.

```
 release {
        buildConfigField "boolean", allowRootCheck, "true"

    }
```

However, for pentesting puposes I need to create a flavor where I can change a number of things tailored to the pentesters needs. One of them is not checking for root. I've tried the following

```
        pentesting {
        dimension "dataSource"
        applicationIdSuffix ".pentesting"
        versionNameSuffix "-pentesting"
        buildConfigField "boolean", allowRootCheck, "false"
    }
```

and while it does compile and build ok, testing the pentestingRelease version of the app on the emulator still triggers the root check, so I guess I'm not overriding it correctly.

Since the pentesters do test periodically the app and do require quite a number of changes, I'd rather have those changes contained within their flavor and not fiddle in sections that are appwide (like release buildtype) if only to avoid some "I forgot to revert that change back before deploying the new version to Play". Is this possible? How?